# Inserting a disconnected recordset into a dictionary object?

Tags: asp-classic

Just wondering if anyone has seen this issue, when trying to insert items from a disconnected recordset into a classic ASP dictionary object I get the error "This key is already associated with an element of this collection".

This is not the case, all the key elements are unique, yes I triple checked the data :)

If I shove the data into a local variable it works fine (see code below). While I'm okay with this has anyone else seen this issue or know why it doesn't work?

```vb
Set Options=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

function Populate(ID) ' WORKS
    Dim strsql, rs, name, id
    if Options.Count = 0 then
        strsql = "select name, ID from options where unique = " & SafeSQL(ID)
        Set rs = RunSQLReturnRS(strsql, null, "Populate") ' returns a disconnected recordset
        do while not rs.eof
            name = rs("name")
            id = rs("id")
            Options.Add name, id
            rs.movenext
        loop
        rs.close
    end if
end function

function Populate2(ID) ' DOES NOT WORK
    Dim strsql, rs
    if Options.Count = 0 then
        strsql = "select name, ID from options where unique = " & SafeSQL(ID)
        Set rs = RunSQLReturnRS(strsql, null, "Populate") ' returns a disconnected recordset
        do while not rs.eof
            Options.Add rs("name"), rs("id")
            rs.movenext
        loop
        rs.close
    end if
end function
```

By request of user Shadow Wizard, the disconnected record function, (note my_conn is the database connection and already is open by the time this function is called)

```
  Function RunSQLReturnRS(sqlstmt, params(), fromfunction)
    ''//Create the ADO objects
    Dim rs, cmd

    Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If Not zerolength(sqlstmt) then
      Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

      ''//Init the ADO objects  & the stored proc parameters
      cmd.ActiveConnection = my_conn
      cmd.CommandText = sqlstmt
      cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
      cmd.CommandTimeout = 900

      ''// propietary function that put params in the cmd
      collectParams cmd, params

      ''//Execute the query for readonly
      rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
      On Error Resume Next
        rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Response.write "Error: "&Err.Description & "<br>fromfunction=" & fromfunction & "<br>" : Response.end
      On Error Goto 0
      ''// Disconnect the recordset
      Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
      Set cmd = Nothing
      Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End if
    ''// Return the resultant recordset
    Set RunSQLReturnRS = rs
  End Function
```

Comment: i suppose because in 2nd sample you are inserting references to fields. that is why it doens't work with disconnected db. i first sample you inserting value (i also always doing on this way).

Comment: For the record, this is **not** a disconnected recordset. This is a live recordset. Disconnected recordset refers to a Recordset you create yourself from scratch (not from database) and manually add fields and values. Just semantics, but wanted to let you know that you're using wrong terms. :)

Comment: Seems a little strange, it's "disconnected" from the data source, how you source the data shouldn't matter, I dump the active connection.... perhaps I should call it a zombie recordset :)

Comment: But you're not disconnecting it, just using a function to return it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this was somewhat tricky but I figured what happened.

The `Add()` method of the VBScript Dictionary object is accepting an *Object* for both key and value arguments. This object can be of any type: number, string, date, complex type etc.

Something that is not commonly known is that when you write `rs("name")` where "rs" is of type Recordset, it does not return a primitive type but rather it returns a **Field object**.

However, if you try to assign it to local variable, VBScript is smart enough to look for a Default Property of that object and if present, execute it. Field object does have such property, which returns the Value of the field.

When you have this:

```
name = rs("name")
```

It actually means:

```
name = rs("name").Value
```

So in your first method, you are giving a string as key, and all is good. In your second method, you pass the Field object itself, and VBScript lack a proper comparison mechanism between Field objects so it thinks they're all the same.

To have the second method work without using local variables, change it to this:

```
do while not rs.eof
    Options.Add rs("name").Value, rs("id").Value
    rs.movenext
loop
```

Comment: There are no dupe keys, please look at the code you will see it uses the SAME data in both examples and the second function works fine with the EXACT same content, the only different is I first put the dictionary data into a local variable before inserting it into the dictionary.

This is a false error message (it shouldn't error) or even a bug in ASP. Please feel free to test it yourself.

Comment: I've added RunSQLReturnRS function as requested

Comment: Oh my. Sorry @silver, I was wrong. Since it's still fresh I took the liberty to radically change the answer to make it correct, please see it now.

Comment: Actually didn't test it myself so hope I'm not totally wrong here... let me know if it's really working.

Comment: Ok, it was a nice try and looked logical. I tested it just now, it doesn't fix the issue I'm afraid. I get a Type mismatch error if I used rs("id").value (for example), which is really weird.

Comment: Oh noes... will have to perform full test locally then.

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I can think of is that the returned recordset essentially "functions like" a dictionary object and trying to copy this value from a "dictionary like" to dictionary is causing the error. I wary to say this but it smells like an ASP bug?